# wxImage Scale() causing image to become distorted

Tags: python, image, wxpython, scipy, wxwidgets

I am trying to zoom in on an image by basically cropping the dimensions of the original image based on the zoom value. My image is an RGBA numpy array. In order to display it in wxPython, I convert it to a wxImage and then use the `Scale()` function to display it at the correct size of the StaticBitmap. The problem is, in certain areas (mainly near the lower left and upper right corners), my image looks like this (at certain zoom "ticks"):

[image]

Whereas the tick right before it (less zoom) looks like this:

[image]

If use `scipy.misc.imresize()` on the numpy array and then convert it to wxImage for display, the issue goes away. The reason I would rather not do it this way is speed. It is much slower, so the zoom feels much less fluid. I am fairly certain this has something to do with the `Scale()` function, although I am not sure what the issue is. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try FloatCanvas? It has zooming built-in and might support this functionality better

Comment: @MikeDriscoll I just looked into it. After going through some examples and looking at some of the code, I don't think this will be very helpful, unfortunately. The way I  am zooming now allows for zooming in smaller increments and navigation is much quicker (uses a slider or mouse wheel). I also need to be able to rotate, and I don't know how long it would take to integrate that. Do you know if it is possible to just use the canvas part and have my own navigation that could interface with the zoom function? Also, can it display 2-D float array images (or RGB images, I can convert)?

Comment: I'm not sure, although I thought it could rotate images and it uses NumPy, so I thought it would be pretty fast. You should repost your question to the wxPython Google group. They might have some good ideas over there.

Answer (score 0):

If you care about the quality of the result (i.e. unless you just want to generate small thumbnails as quickly as possible), you should use `wxImage::Scale()` with `wxIMAGE_QUALITY_HIGH` instead of its default `wxIMAGE_QUALITY_NORMAL` quality.

If this doesn't fix the issues you're seeing, it would be interesting to see the images reproducing the problem (please create a ticket on [wxTrac](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/) and upload them there).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I already tried that and had the same results. I tried to open a ticket, but I need to be registered and when I try to register I get this error: "URLError: (-2, 'Name or service not known'"